# Nvidia DIGITS: Loss coverage (val and train) go straight to zero

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network, pycaffe, nvidia-digits

### **EDIT: FOUND THE PROBLEM. I forgot to add a custom class when creating the dataset. Amateur mistake, but leaving this up for others who make a similar error.**

After successfully following the KITTI tutorial provided by NVIDIA, I began trying to run DIGITS on my own dataset. The problem is that almost immediately after starting, **the loss coverage for both the train and validation goes straight to almost zero**, on the scale of 10e-4 loss.

[This is a picture of the loss as a function of the epoch (account is too new to embed image).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeN7A.png)

Extra details:

- ~900 training images and ~300 validation images (Note: I have been told by a friend that he got it to work with this data set, so I don't believe the number of images is the problem)
- The images are very simple and contain a model of a car on a mostly plain background.
- I had to create the validation data by taking images/labels from the training data
- The model I used is the DetectNet model mentioned in the [DIGITS object detection tutorial.](https://github.com/NVIDIA/DIGITS/tree/master/examples/object-detection)
- I used the GoogLeNet pretrained model also mentioned in the tutorial.

What I tried:

- Changing the hyperparameters appears to do nothing
- As mentioned earlier, running the model for longer than 1 epoch does not change anything (loss coverage stays close to zero)